# How is Illegal char's URL working?

Tags: algorithm, url

There are many sites (such as Stackoverflow) that has the title of the page in the URL.
I am looking for the algorithm in which they are using in order to avoid illegal URL characters.  ( I dont want URL encoding, I want replace/remove algo)

like 'How is Illegal char's URL working?' will become 'How-is-Illegal-chars-URL-working'

Thanks!

Comment: It's the same as any other string replacement algo: decide which chars you don't want and then replace them with an alternative (or nothing).

Comment: There is something ready already someone did, I am looking for the all-thought-of algorithm

Comment: What language are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea how SO does it, but I would just strip every non-alphanumeric character and replace spaces with underscores.

In Python:

```
def cleanTitle(title):
  temp = ''

  for character in title.lower():
    if character in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890_-+/<>,.=[]{}()\|!@#$%^&':
      temp += character

  return temp
```

I see you are working in C#. I don't know C#, so you'll have to translate this code. I doubt it's hard to do, though.

Comment: I used your idea in a different way. Thanks!

Comment: Shorter blender: `title = str(x for x in title.lower() if x in 'abcd...')`

Comment: @NickJohnson: I'm just being verbose. It's easier to translate in to C# ;)

Comment: Oops, I missed the mention of C#.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm to do this is generally called '[slugify](http://www.google.com.au/search?gcx=c&ix=c2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=slugify)', because it turns a string into a 'slug' to be used in a URL. Searching for that should give you plenty of useful implementations.